# angular getting error on `input type number` , ngModel:numfmt on "01234"

Tags: angularjs, input, numbers, angular-ngmodel

i have an error on setting a value in controller like this `01234` and turning it to string for not removing the `0`

and getting error on `input type number` for using the `string` as a value , i want to showing the zero in input field and cant switch to `input type text` !

Comment: But if you want to process a number, then why you need the `0` at first place?

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach because its a phone number , and it must send the 0 to backend , and i cant change the type number , because i want the numpad keys on mobile phones !

Comment: just use `type="tel"`. By the way ios doesn't support type `number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use type `tel`

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="myNumber">
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.myNumber = "01234";
```

See this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5GQiLpENthi7ccok5hJ?p=preview
[image]